# Funcionamiento de StringBuilder en C# respecto a asignaciones

Tags: c#

Estoy aprendiendo C# y he empezado hace poco a usar StringBuilder.
Tengo una tarea que consiste en quitar espacios en blanco de una cadena mediante un método que recibe dicha cadena. El método que he realizado en una clase denominada "Cadenas" es el siguiente:

```
    // Quita los espacios en blanco de una cadena de caracteres
    public StringBuilder SuprimeEspaciosBlanco(StringBuilder cadena)
    {
        // Creamos las variables
        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();       // Almacena la nueva cadena

        resultado = cadena;     // Asignamos la cadena original a resultado, que se irá modificando


        // Recorremos la cadena
        for (int i = 0; i < resultado.Length; i++)
        {
            char letra = resultado.ToString().ToLower()[i];                      // Asignamos la letra de la posición actual

            // Si estamos en un espacio
            if (letra == ' ')
            {
                resultado.Remove(i, 1);     // Quitamos el espacio
            }
        }


        return resultado;       // Devolvemos la cadena resultante
    }
```

El método es llamado por la clase estática "Principal", cuyas partes en la que se asignan los datos a la cadena y en la que se llama al método son las siguientes:

```
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("========== Introducción de datos ==========");
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Se pide al usuario la cadena a comprobar y se asigna
            Console.Write("Introduzca la cadena: ");
            StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder(Console.ReadLine());
            StringBuilder cadenaMod = new StringBuilder();



            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("========== Eliminación de espacios en blanco ==========");
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Enviamos la cadena a SuprimeEspaciosBlanco para que quite los espacios de la cadena
            cadenaMod = objCadena.SuprimeEspaciosBlanco(cadena);

            // Indicamos la nueva cadena
            Console.WriteLine("Cadena de caracteres original: \"{0}\"", cadena);
            Console.WriteLine("Cadena de caracteres nueva: \"{0}\"", cadenaMod);
```

Añado que cadenaMod se supone que almacena el resultado modificado de cadena una vez los espacios se han quitado, es decir, que cadena debe seguir almacenando el valor inicial, es por ello que he creado un StringBuilder adicional para evitar modificar los datos originales.

El problema surge cuando ejecuto el programa y, al quitarse cada espacio, no se hace sólo en resultado, sino también en cadena. Mi duda principal es por qué lo hace, dado que, revisando desde mi punto de vista novato, el método Remove en SuprimeEspaciosBlanco lo utiliza resultado, no cadena.

¿Puede ser que al asignar cadena a resultado compartan la dirección de memoria en vez de la cadena, y al modificar resultado se modifique el contenido de dicha dirección de memoria? Si fuera eso, ¿cómo podría solucionarlo? ¿Con un CopyTo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder(cadena.ToString()); asi no tendras la referencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que `StringBuilder` es un objeto, por lo tanto si lo asignas entre variables lo que realmente estas asignando es el puntero a ese valor, no se esta copiando el contenido.

Si usaras tipos como ser `string`, `int`, `decimal`, etc al asignar variables estas si asignan el contenido porque son tipos nativos. Lo cual no sucede con `StringBuilder`

Para crear una copia deberias usar algo como esto

```
public StringBuilder SuprimeEspaciosBlanco(StringBuilder cadena)
{

    StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder(cadena.ToString());       


    for (int i = 0; i < resultado.Length; i++)
    {
     //resto codigo
```

como observarias el parametro lo pasas a `string` para tener solo el valor simple que usaras en una nueva instancia de `StringBuilder`